# Are there any downside of increasing sendtimeout in WcfBinding?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

My application calls a 3rd party WCF service and chances are that it get time-out 10 in 100 times.

What should i do, should i increase the SendTimeout, are there any downside of it.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save some investigation. Timeout may be caused by broken connectivity, network overload or server overload. And be aware: using longer timeouts will cause more load on both servers -- your and the 3rd party as well.
Timeout is usually not the problem itself, just a symptom of it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, negative is - your applicaiton will possibly wait longer in case of a failure. THat said, if the other side just normally takes longer, adjust the timeout. THere is not a lot else you can do.